# Codeigniter calendar library to display week and month

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, calendar, libraries

i'm searching a way to display data for week and month.

For now, i can click on a day of the calendar and see the data related to this day.

For example, i'd like to choose the week number 5(or a month) of year 2013 and see the data related.

Any idea of how to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: Please refer this link http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/98438/ and http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/180065/.

Answer (score 0):

i found out the solution:

My controller script:

```
$p = new DatePeriod(
new DateTime('2013-09-01'), 
new DateInterval('P1W'), 
new DateTime($today)
);
$data['weeks'] = array();
$data['month'] = array();
foreach ($p as $w) {
$data['weeks'][$w->format('W')] = $w->format('Y').' - Week '.$w->format('W');
$data['month'][$w->format('m')] = $w->format('Y').' - Month '.$w->format('m');
}
```

My view script:

```
<?php
// display for weeks
echo form_dropdown('week', $weeks, $lastWeek);
// display for month
echo form_dropdown('month', $month, $lastMonth);
?>
```